# Where is the mistake?

Tags: c++, linked-list

i am implementing a simple linked list in c++.
I have a mistake and i don't see it :(

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

struct Node {

    Node(Node *next, int value):
    next(next), value(value) {
    }
    Node *next;
    int value;
};

class List {
    Node *first;
    int len;
    Node *nthNode(int index);

public:

    List():first(0),len(0){
    }

    // Copy - Konstruktor 
    List(const List & other){

    };

    // Zuweisungs - Operator O(len +other.len)
    List &operator=(const List &other) {
        clear();
        if(!other.len) return *this;
        Node *it = first = new Node(0,other.first->value);
        for (Node *n = other.first->next; n; n = n->next) {
            it = it->next = new Node(0, n->value);
        }
        len = other.len;
        return *this;
    }

    // Destruktor 
    ~List(){

    };


    void push_back(int value){

    };

    void push_front(int value){
        Node* front = new Node(0,value);

        if(first){
            first  = front;
            front->next = 0;
        }else{
            front->next = first;
            first = front;

        }
        len++;
    };

    int &at(int index){
        int count = 0 ;
        int ret ;
        Node *it = first;
        for (Node *n = first->next; n; n = n->next) {
            if(count==index) ret = n->value;
            count++;
        }
        return ret ;
    };

    void clear(){


    };

    void show() {
        std::cout << " List [" << len << " ]:{ ";
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            std::cout << at(i) << (i == len - 1 ? '}' : ',');
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

/*
 * 
 */
int main() {

    List l;
 //   l. push_back(1);
 //   l. push_back(2);
    l. push_front(7);
    l. push_front(8);
    l. push_front(9);
    l.show();
   // List(l). show();
}
```

it works ... but the output is :

> List [3 ]:{ 0,134520896,9484585}

Answer (score 3):

The `push_front` logic is wrong. It should look like this:

```
void push_front(int value){
    first = new Node(first, value);
    ++len;
}
```

While we're at it, your `operator=` isn't exception-safe. Implement copying in the copy-constructor and assign using the copy-and-swap idiom:

```
List& operator=(List other) { swap(other); return *this; }
void swap(List& other) {
    Node* tnode = first; first = other.first; other.first = tnode;
    int tlen = len; len = other.len; other.len = tlen;
}
```

On another note, don't implement the `at` member function; random access is very inefficient, and should not be encouraged. Implement iterators instead.

Comment: I dont undestand why for operator = need use swap. If i have 2 lists and then assign one to other, i want that fisrt will be a copy of other or with lazy resource savings head of lists point to one memory place.

Comment: @den bardadym, what state will the list be in if one of the `new Node` invocations fails? The copy-and-swap idiom doesn't alter the target of the assignment until the copy has already succeeded. The swap itself never throws.

Comment: the push_front() has to be like marcelo said, at the at() function you start by the wrong Node* in the list .. you start by first->next, it should be "first".

Comment: I undestand what u mean and why it need, but i dont agree with this idioms. I think all operators must be obvious for undestanding results of executions. But i think such idiom can make some misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a reference to a local variable in `at`. The variable goes out of scope when the function exits. Accessing it afterwards is undefined behavior. You are lucky it does not crash.

You should also reconsider your implementation of show (O(n*n) seriously?) and push_front (if (first) ?).

Here is a better implementation of at:

```
Node *at(int index){
    int count = 0 ;
    for (Node *n = first; n; n = n->next) {
        if(count==index) 
            return n;
        count++;
    }
    return NULL;
};
```

It does not return a reference. You can not return a NULL-reference if index is larger than the length of the list.
I also changed the return type to Node, so the caller can change value.